# Do loop-level three-point scattering amplitudes have branch cuts?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

I know that higher point scattering amplitudes at a sufficiently high loop level have branch cuts and discontinuities. I wonder whether the number of scattering particles plays a role in this?

> Is there a quick way to argue whether three-point scattering amplitudes (in any example theory) have branch cuts at a sufficiently high loop order?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that simple one-loop integrals as evaluated in the paper [Scalar one-loop integrals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321379906059?via%3Dihub) feature functions such as square roots and logarithms for two- and three-point cases, it is clear that three-point amplitudes may develop branch cuts as soon as at one-loop level.